# OpenGL ES 2.0 Android - cube rotation bug

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I implemented the visualization of a colored 3d cube with OpenGL ES 2.0 that is used for an android app. My goal: the cube should react to swipe events (left, right, up, down), then the cube should be **rotated** in the corresponding direction.

**The rotation:**

- stops if (current_angle % 90 == 0) -> so you swipe from one face to another
- only one rotation at a time (and only around x- or y-axis)
- should also be done in steps (ex.: 5 degrees), so it is not done instantly -> can be seen by the user

**My code:**

```
public class Cube20 {

    private volatile int angleX;
    private volatile int angleY;

    private volatile Cube.RotateDirection rotateDirection;

    public Cube.RotateDirection getRotateDirection() {
        return rotateDirection;
    }


    public void setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection rotateDirection) {
        this.rotateDirection = Cube.RotateDirection.getDirectionForID(rotateDirection.getId());
    }

    public int getAngleX() {
        return angleX;
    }

    public void setAngleX(int angleX) {
        this.angleX = angleX;
    }

    public int getAngleY() {
        return angleY;
    }

    public void setAngleY(int angleY) {
        this.angleY = angleY;
    }

    private final String vertexShaderCode =
            // This matrix member variable provides a hook to manipulate
            // the coordinates of the objects that use this vertex shader
            "uniform mat4 uMVPMatrix;" +
                    "attribute vec4 vPosition;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    // The matrix must be included as a modifier of gl_Position.
                    // Note that the uMVPMatrix factor *must be first* in order
                    // for the matrix multiplication product to be correct.
                    "  gl_Position = uMVPMatrix * vPosition;" +
                    "}";

    private final String fragmentShaderCode =
            "precision mediump float;" +
                    "uniform vec4 vColor;" +
                    "void main() {" +
                    "  gl_FragColor = vColor;" +
                    "}";

    private final FloatBuffer vertexBuffer;
    //private final ShortBuffer drawListBuffer;
    private final int mProgram;
    private final ShortBuffer indexBuffer;
    private int mPositionHandle;
    private int mColorHandle;
    private int mMVPMatrixHandle;

    // number of coordinates per vertex in this array
    static final int COORDS_PER_VERTEX = 3;

    private float[] vertices = {  // Vertices of the 6 faces
            // FRONT
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front (0)
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            // BACK
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back (4)
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            // LEFT
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back (8)
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            // RIGHT
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  // 1. right-bottom-front (12)
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            // TOP
            -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 2. left-top-front
            1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f,  // 3. right-top-front
            -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 5. left-top-back
            1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f,  // 7. right-top-back
            // BOTTOM
            -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 4. left-bottom-back
            1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f,  // 6. right-bottom-back
            -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f,  // 0. left-bottom-front
            1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f   // 1. right-bottom-front
    };

    private final int vertexStride = COORDS_PER_VERTEX * 4; // 4 bytes per vertex

    private float[][] colors = {  // Colors of the 6 faces
            {1.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 0. orange
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // 1. violet
            {0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 2. green
            {0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f},  // 3. blue
            {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f},  // 4. red
            {1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f}   // 5. yellow
    };

    short[] indices = {
            0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3, // FRONT
            4, 5, 6, 6, 5, 7, // BACK
            8, 9, 10, 10, 9, 11, // LEFT
            12, 13, 14, 14, 13, 15, // RIGHT
            16, 17, 18, 18, 17, 19, // TOP
            20, 21, 22, 22, 21, 23, // BOTTOM

    };
    private int numFaces = 6;

    /**
     * Sets up the drawing object data for use in an OpenGL ES context.
     */
    public Cube20() {
        // initialize vertex byte buffer for shape coordinates
        ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(
                // (# of coordinate values * 4 bytes per float)
                vertices.length * 4);
        bb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
        vertexBuffer = bb.asFloatBuffer();
        vertexBuffer.put(vertices);
        vertexBuffer.position(0);

        // initialize byte buffer for the draw list
        indexBuffer = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(indices.length * 2).order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder()).asShortBuffer();
        indexBuffer.put(indices).position(0);

        // prepare shaders and OpenGL program
        int vertexShader = RenderUtils.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_VERTEX_SHADER,
                vertexShaderCode);
        int fragmentShader = RenderUtils.loadShader(
                GLES20.GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER,
                fragmentShaderCode);

        mProgram = GLES20.glCreateProgram();             // create empty OpenGL Program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, vertexShader);   // add the vertex shader to program
        GLES20.glAttachShader(mProgram, fragmentShader); // add the fragment shader to program
        GLES20.glLinkProgram(mProgram);                  // create OpenGL program executables

        this.rotateDirection = Cube.RotateDirection.NONE;
    }

    /**
     * Encapsulates the OpenGL ES instructions for drawing this shape.
     *
     * @param mvpMatrix - The Model View Project matrix in which to draw
     *                  this shape.
     */
    public void draw(float[] mvpMatrix) {
        // Add program to OpenGL environment
        GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgram);

        GLES20.glFrontFace(GLES20.GL_CCW);
        GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
        GLES20.glCullFace(GLES20.GL_BACK);

        // scale
        float scale_matrix[] = new float[16];
        Matrix.setIdentityM(scale_matrix, 0);
        Matrix.scaleM(scale_matrix, 0, 0.5f, 0.5f, 1);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mvpMatrix, 0, scale_matrix, 0, mvpMatrix, 0);

        // get handle to vertex shader's vPosition member
        mPositionHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgram, "vPosition");

        // Enable a handle to the triangle vertices
        GLES20.glEnableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);

        // Prepare the triangle coordinate data
        GLES20.glVertexAttribPointer(
                mPositionHandle, COORDS_PER_VERTEX,
                GLES20.GL_FLOAT, false,
                vertexStride, vertexBuffer);

        // get handle to fragment shader's vColor member
        mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "vColor");

        // Set color for drawing the triangle
        //GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, color, 0);

        // get handle to shape's transformation matrix
        mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgram, "uMVPMatrix");
        RenderUtils.checkGlError("glGetUniformLocation");

        // Apply the projection and view transformation
        GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMVPMatrixHandle, 1, false, mvpMatrix, 0);
        RenderUtils.checkGlError("glUniformMatrix4fv");

        // Render all the faces
        for (int face = 0; face < numFaces; face++) {
            // Set the color for each of the faces
            GLES20.glUniform4fv(mColorHandle, 1, colors[face], 0);
            indexBuffer.position(face * 6);
            GLES20.glDrawElements(GLES20.GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, indexBuffer);
        }

        // Disable vertex array
        GLES20.glDisableVertexAttribArray(mPositionHandle);
        GLES20.glDisable(GLES20.GL_CULL_FACE);
    }
}

public class MyGLSurfaceView extends GLSurfaceView {
    private volatile MyGLRenderer myGLRenderer;

    public MyGLSurfaceView(Context context) {
        super(context);

        // Create an OpenGL ES 2.0 context
        setEGLContextClientVersion(2);

        myGLRenderer = new MyGLRenderer(context);
        setRenderer(myGLRenderer); // Use a custom renderer
        setOnTouchListener(new OnSwipeListener(context));

        setRenderMode(GLSurfaceView.RENDERMODE_CONTINUOUSLY);
    }

    class OnSwipeListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

        private final GestureDetector gestureDetector;

        public OnSwipeListener(Context context) {
            this.gestureDetector = new GestureDetector(context, new OnFlingListener());
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return this.gestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
        }

        private class OnFlingListener extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
            private final Object LOCK = new Object();

            @Override
            public boolean onDown(MotionEvent e) {
                return true;
            }

            /**
             * @return true if the event is consumed, else false
             */
            @Override
            public boolean onFling(MotionEvent down, MotionEvent up, float velocityX, float velocityY) {
                //super.onFling(down, up, velocityX, velocityY);

                float distanceX = up.getX() - down.getX();
                float distanceY = up.getY() - down.getY();

                final Cube20 cube = myGLRenderer.getCube();
                if (!cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.NONE)) {
                    return false;
                }

                if (Math.abs(distanceX) > Math.abs(distanceY)) {
                    if (distanceX > 0) {
                        // RIGHT
                        cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.RIGHT);
                    } else {
                        // LEFT
                        cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.LEFT);
                    }
                } else {
                    if (distanceY < 0) {
                        // TOP
                        cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.UP);
                    } else {
                        // DOWN
                        cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.DOWN);
                    }
                }
                //requestRender();
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}

public class MyGLRenderer implements GLSurfaceView.Renderer {
    Context context;   // Application's context
    private volatile int rotationAngle;
    private volatile float rotateX;
    private volatile float rotateY;
    private boolean firstRotation = true;
    private Cube20 cube;

    // mMVPMatrix is an abbreviation for "Model View Projection Matrix"
    private final float[] mMVPMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mProjectionMatrix = new float[16];
    private final float[] mViewMatrix = new float[16];

    // Constructor with global application context
    public MyGLRenderer(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }


    public float getRotateX() {
        return rotateX;
    }

    public void setRotateX(float rotateX) {
        this.rotateX = rotateX;
    }

    public float getRotateY() {
        return rotateY;
    }

    public void setRotateY(float rotateY) {
        this.rotateY = rotateY;
    }

    public float getAngle() {
        return rotationAngle;
    }

    public void setAngle(int angle) {
        rotationAngle = angle;
    }


    // Call back when the surface is first created or re-created
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
        // Set the background frame color
        GLES20.glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
        this.cube = new Cube20();
    }

    // Call back to draw the current frame.
    @Override
    public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
        // Redraw background color
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

        // Set the camera position (View matrix)
        Matrix.setLookAtM(mViewMatrix, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0f, 0f, 0f, 0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

        // Calculate the projection and view transformation
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mProjectionMatrix, 0, mViewMatrix, 0);

        // zoom out a bit
        Matrix.translateM(mMVPMatrix, 0, 0, 0, 4.5f);


        int angleOffset = 5;
        // update the angles for the x and y rotation
        if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.LEFT)) {
            cube.setAngleY(cube.getAngleY() - angleOffset);
        } else if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.RIGHT)) {
            cube.setAngleY(cube.getAngleY() + angleOffset);
        } else if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.UP)) {
            cube.setAngleX(cube.getAngleX() + angleOffset);
        } else if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.DOWN)) {
            cube.setAngleX(cube.getAngleX() - angleOffset);
        }
        firstRotation = false;

        // rotate and draw
        rotate();
        cube.draw(mMVPMatrix);


        // test if rotation should be stopped (lock in each 90° step)
        if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.LEFT) ||
                cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.RIGHT)) {
            if (!firstRotation && cube.getAngleY() % 90 == 0) {
                cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.NONE);
            }
        }
        if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.UP) ||
                cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.DOWN)) {
            if (!firstRotation && cube.getAngleX() % 90 == 0) {
                cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.NONE);
            }
        }

        Log.i("MyGLRENDER~ ", cube.getRotateDirection().toString());
    }

    private void rotate() {
        float[] rotationMatrix = new float[16];
        Matrix.setIdentityM(rotationMatrix, 0);

        // rotate in x and y direction, apply that to the intermediate matrix
        Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, cube.getAngleX(), 1, 0, 0);
        Matrix.rotateM(rotationMatrix, 0, cube.getAngleY(), 0, 1, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, rotationMatrix, 0);
    }

    // Call back after onSurfaceCreated() or whenever the window's size changes
    @Override
    public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
        GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
        float ratio = (float) width / height;

        // this projection matrix is applied to object coordinates
        // in the onDrawFrame() method
        Matrix.frustumM(mProjectionMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, 3, 7);
    }

    public Cube20 getCube() {
        return cube;
    }
}

public class MyGLActivity extends Activity {

    private GLSurfaceView glView;   // Use GLSurfaceView

    // Call back when the activity is started, to initialize the view
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        glView = new MyGLSurfaceView(this); // Allocate a GLSurfaceView
        this.setContentView(glView); // This activity sets to GLSurfaceView
    }

    // Call back when the activity is going into the background
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        glView.onPause();
    }

    // Call back after onPause()
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        glView.onResume();
    }
}
```

**The behaviour im expecting:**

- successful swipe reaction and rotation about x-axis
  [image: (intermediate screenshot)]
- successful swipe reaction and rotation about y-axis
  [image: (intermediate screenshot)]

**With this setup i encounter the following problems:**

1. Sometimes the rotation is done about the z-axis
   [image: (intermediate screenshot)]
   I never implemented a rotation about the z-axis for the cube, i am not sure why this rotation is done. I could only imagine that there is maybe a threading problem between the swipe listener at `MyGLSurfaceView` and `MyGLRenderer` (which holds the reference to the cube).

The rotation is done at `MyGLRenderer.rotate`. The cube uses separate angles (x/y) and also there is a property for which rotation is currently done (LEFT, RIGHT, UP, DOWN, NONE), which is updated in `OnSwipeListener`.

2. Also if the bug with the z-rotation (1.) happened, the rotation about the x or y axis is done in the **wrong** direction (left/right, up/down swapped)

My guess is that either the angles or the `RotateDirection` is not updated correctly.
The app is tested on a OnePlus 3T @ Android 8.0, IDE is Android Studio 3.2.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have rotated a cube by 90° around the X-axis, then of course a rotation on around the Y-axis of the cube is a rotation around the Z-axis in the world. You have to rotate around the Y-axis of the world, not around the Y-axis of the cube.
To do so you have to store the concatenated rotations of the  cube in a rotation matrix and to apply the new rotation to this matrix.

Create a member for rotation matrix:

```
private final float[] mRotationMatrix = new float[16];
```

Initialize it by the identity matrix:

```
Matrix.setIdentityM(mRotationMatrix, 0);
```

In the method `rotate` you have to apply the current animation to the rotation matrix. The order has to be `animationMatrix * mRotationMatrix`. The matrix multiplication is not  [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property). If you don't respect the order of the multiplication you will get the same result as before and the rotation would be around the axis of the cube and not around the axis of the world.

```
private void rotate() {
    float[] animationMatrix = new float[16];
    Matrix.setIdentityM(animationMatrix, 0);

    // rotate in x and y direction, apply that to the intermediate matrix
    Matrix.rotateM(animationMatrix, 0, cube.getAngleX(), 1, 0, 0);
    Matrix.rotateM(animationMatrix, 0, cube.getAngleY(), 0, 1, 0);

    // concatenate the animation and the rotation matrix; the order is important
    Matrix.multiplyMM(animationMatrix, 0, animationMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0); 

    Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mMVPMatrix, 0, animationMatrix, 0);
}
```

When the animation has reached full 90° then you have to change the rotation matrix and to reset the rotation angle:

```
if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.LEFT) ||
    cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.RIGHT)) {
        if (!firstRotation && cube.getAngleY() % 90 == 0) {

            float[] newRotationMatrix = new float[16];
            Matrix.setIdentityM(newRotationMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.rotateM(newRotationMatrix, 0, cube.getAngleY(), 0, 1, 0);

            // concatenate the new 90 rotation to the rotation matrix
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotationMatrix, 0, newRotationMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

            // reset the angle
            cube.setAngleY(0);
            cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.NONE);
        }
    }
    if (cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.UP) ||
        cube.getRotateDirection().equals(Cube.RotateDirection.DOWN)) {
        if (!firstRotation && cube.getAngleX() % 90 == 0) {

            float[] newRotationMatrix = new float[16];
            Matrix.setIdentityM(newRotationMatrix, 0);
            Matrix.rotateM(newRotationMatrix, 0, cube.getAngleX(), 1, 0, 0);

            // concatenate the new 90 rotation to the rotation matrix
            Matrix.multiplyMM(mRotationMatrix, 0, newRotationMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

            // reset the angle
            cube.setAngleX(0);
            cube.setRotation(Cube.RotateDirection.NONE);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, works like a charm now! So basically, i already had this idea and wanted to rotate about the axis of the world. But meanwhile i was actually rotating the whole axis-system of the world and not correctly rotating the cube, right?

Comment: @MatthiasTietz The issue is that your original code does `rotateX * rotateY`. This would work if the first rotation is around the Y-axis and the 2nd is around the X-axis, but it won't work if the first rotation is around the X and the 2nd is around Y. Then you would have to do `rotateY * rotateX`. If you want 1 rotation around X than around Y and a 3rd again around X, then you would have to do `rotateX2*rotateY*rotateX1`. This is what the code of the answer does, because all previous rotations are *collected* in `mRotationMatrix`.